# Disable force push warning in Intellij

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I branch and force push a lot. Every time I force push on a new branch, I have to confirm this and tell intellij not to warn me about this branch anymore.

Is there a way to allow force push by default on all branches? I don't want to have to click "don't warn me anymore".

Hey - git itself doesn't ask me to confirm this, why should my IDE?

Comment: IDEs usually have limited support for other tools, especially for tools like git. What if you break your habits using `git` directly in your shell not using the VCS plugin in IntelliJ IDEA? It would be 100x times more powerful, wouldn't it?

Comment: @fluffy it's certainly an option, and I agree that being able to use the shell is a good thing. I can use the shell, but the IDE is faster for me.

Comment: But why do you use so often `git push --force`? Then `force` modifying the git history and can get your collaborators out of sync. Or are you working alone on a branch, then force pushing does not affect anyone else.

Comment: IDE is trying to prevent any potentially destructive actions being performed thus shows you such a window.
There is no option to disable it completely on a project level. IDE wants you to be safe and "Force push" can be quite harmful action. git in command-line may not warn you about it since you have to type `--force` which implies that you are doing this on purpose, whereas when you do it via any UI - it can be either miss-click or wrong shortcut and it's better to prevent or let a user know about operation.

Comment: We work with short-lived branches, usually pushed by one person, and collaborators know that history rewrites happen. The default branch is protected. So not much can go wrong. I like to use amend a lot to keep my commit history clean.